# LINQ Select top n distinct dates in date time field order by descending

Tags: c#, linq

How do I select top n distinct dates from datetime field order by descending in LINQ C#. I have input and output something like below

Input
2020-01-23 09:15:11.953
2020-01-30 09:15:11.613
2020-02-01 09:15:31.427
2020-02-06 10:08:44.530
2020-02-11 09:20:01.707
2020-02-11 10:22:01.707
2020-02-14 09:16:00.977
2020-02-18 09:16:02.227
2020-02-18 11:26:02.227
2020-02-18 09:16:02.227
2020-03-04 12:33:17.257
2020-03-05 11:20:55.167
2020-03-05 13:28:55.167

Output for Top 3 descending should give

2020-03-05
2020-03-04
2020-02-18

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`GroupBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby) and [`Distinct`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct) together as follow:

```
List<DateTime> dates = new List<DateTime>()
{
    DateTime.Parse("2020-01-23 09:15:11.953"),
     DateTime.Parse("2020-01-30 09:15:11.613"),
     DateTime.Parse("2020-02-01 09:15:31.427"),
     DateTime.Parse("2020-02-06 10:08:44.530"),
     DateTime.Parse("2020-02-11 09:20:01.707"),
     DateTime.Parse("2020-02-11 10:22:01.707"),
     DateTime.Parse("2020-02-14 09:16:00.977"),
     DateTime.Parse("2020-02-18 09:16:02.227"),
     DateTime.Parse("2020-02-18 11:26:02.227"),
     DateTime.Parse("2020-02-18 09:16:02.227"),
     DateTime.Parse("2020-03-04 12:33:17.257"),
     DateTime.Parse("2020-03-05 11:20:55.167"),
     DateTime.Parse("2020-03-05 13:28:55.167")
};

var result = dates.OrderByDescending(o => o).GroupBy(g => g.Date).Distinct().Take(3).Select(s => s.Key).ToList();
```

Comment: You are welcome, please mark an answer as accepted by clicking the check-mark as well.

Comment: Just to make it work for my scenario, had to do little addition to your code to make it work on database field. Might be helpful for someone. Following is complete code                                                                                 
        List<DateTime> tradesDatesSorted = ctx.StockTrade
                                        .Select(p => p.BuyTime)
                                        .ToList<DateTime>()
                                        .OrderByDescending(o => o).GroupBy(g => g.Date).Distinct().Take(3).Select(s => s.Key).ToList();